# Communication between node.js daemon and external GUI client

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, client, daemon

I would like to create a daemon in Node.js and use another language to write external GUI (probably Python). What should I use to communicate between them?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if it's possible by you to have your node.js daemon to run a webservice with node.js built in web server, that way you can communicate over http and use the REST style of software architecture.

Comment: But it isn't the standard solution for this kind of problems, is it? I thought rather about something like signals between processes, but I don't know how to do this in a cross-platform way.

Comment: wouldn't say it's a standart but communicating over HTTP is in use today by a lot of applications, i.e CouchDB, MongoDB got a REST interface

Comment: The problem is, that I want to write a realtime application. Websockets would be better in this case than HTTP. But still, I would like to avoid opening port for a system application.

Comment: in that case yes your better of with unix sockets, node.js can do it, http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.4/api/net.html#socket.connect.